# If I want to override the resource path (e.g. post_path(@post)), where do I do that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

UPDATE (again) | Ignore the module thing-o I put up here before.  Better off just using `to_param` and making the routes work.

```
to_param
  if slug
    "#{id}-#{slug}"
  else
    super
  end
end

match "/posts/:id(-:slug)" => "posts#show", :as => :post, :constraints => { :id => /\d+|\d+-.*/ }
```

The trick is in that route.  It makes `-:slug` optional, and adds a constraint to `:id`.  The constraint's preference is to match just a numeric value (which is what gets used when a request comes in, so you have `:id` and `:slug` in your params), but the pipe allows it to also match a numeric value followed by the slug, for the purpose of route generation.  It's a mild hack, but this whole thing is really.  Allowing resource to provide a hash of params would solve this.  This could be applied to any fancy route you want (e.g. having the `:id` at the end instead of the start).

Rails 3.0.7.

Take a route like:

```
match "/posts/:id-:slug" => "posts#show", :as => :post
```

This provides a `post_path(obj)` helper for me, but of course, it only wants to generate a single argument from my model, and from what I can tell, there's no way to return multiple values from my models' `to_param` method.  I know I can write `to_param` like this:

```
to_param
  "#{id}-#{slug}"
end
```

But this is passed as a single argument to the route, which ultimately doesn't match any routes.  Similarly, I know I can remove the `"-:slug"` from my route, but then the `:id` parameter contains bogus input and is basically a bit of a hack (though apparently the done thing).

It'd be awesome if a future version of Rails let you return a hash from `to_param`, like:

```
to_param
  { :id => id, :slug => slug }
end
```

then used those when locating the correct route to use.

What I'm trying to figure out, is where I would go about overriding `post_path()` to provide the correct route.  I can put it in a view helper, but then it's not available in my controllers, so I'm guessing this is the wrong place to do it.

Just curious more than anything.  I know it works fine if I just omit the `:slug` on the route, but in a more complex situation I can imagine overriding the default paths to be a useful thing to know.  Being able to generate a route just by passing a resource is a pretty nice feature I'd like to adopts, but the marketing dept will always have us filling the URLs will all kinds of keywords mumbo jumbo, so some control would be excellent :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two sides to routing: route **generation** and route **matching**.

The **route generation**, as you point out, is quite easy. Override `to_param` in any ActiveModel:

```
# In a model:
def to_param
  # Use another column instead of the primary key 'id':
  awesome_identifier.to_s
end
```

The **route matching** is less obvious. It is possible to specify `:awesome_identifier` in place of every occurrence of `:id` in the default resource routes. However, I have found that Rails will give you less resistance if you leave `:id` in your routes, and **only change the logic in your controller**. Note that this is a trade-off, because fundamentally the `:id` in your routes is not really correct.

```
# In a controller:
def index
  @awesome_record = AwesomeModel.find_by_awesome_identifier(params[:id])
  # ...
end
```

As you have noted, Rails has **optimised a single use case**: if you want the primary key to be used for quick record look-up, but still prefer a slug to be included in the URL for user-friendliness or search engine optimisation. In that case you can return a string of the form `"#{id}-#{whatever}"` from the `to_param` method, and everything after the dash will be ignored when feeding the same string back into the `find` method.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know where Rails looks for the `post_path()` method?  Overriding it in the controller means it's not available to the view. Overriding it in the helper means it's not available to the controller.  I'm thinking of making a module and including it into both the helpers and the controller.  I understand that I should really just use :id, even though it's not correct, but it will chew away in the back of my mind as to what the cleanest way to avoid it is ;)

Comment: Well this works, though I'm not entirely sure it's the "best" way.  Create a module called `CustomPaths`, then in `ApplicationController`, include that module, and also in `ApplicationHelper`, include the module to make it available to your views.  Now `link_to` and friends will see any `*_path` methods here first.

Comment: I really don't think you should try and override the URL helper methods. It is much easier to implement a different `to_param` method, which will do what you need. It is the *route matching* part that is more tricky to accomplish.

Comment: I think you're right.  You can cheat a bit with the routes: `"/posts/:id(-:slug)" ... :constraints => { :id => /\d+|\d+-.*/ }`.  It's a bit of jiggery pokery, but basically it means the route can be generated with `:id => "123-slug-here"`, but when the request comes in, it's split into `:id` and `:slug` params.